# Force between two blocks on a friction-less surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

The question is,

> A single horizontal force $F$ is applied to a block of mass $M_1$ which is in contact with
>   another block of mass $M_2$ as shown in the figure.
>
> [image]
>
> The surfaces are friction-less.
>
> 1. What will be the force between the blocks?
>
> [image]

2. I have another question. If the blocks are in contact and they do not have elasticity, should not the force between them be $F$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. The key is that both the bodies move with the same acceleration. This is proven by Newton's first law and that both the bodies are perfectly rigid.

If they move with the same acceleration we can consider both the bodies as one body of mass $M_1 + M_2$. Newtons second law is $\Sigma$$F=ma$, so the acceleration of both the bodies is $F/(M_1+M_2)$.

Now think of them as two separate bodies. $M_2$ has to move with an acceleration of $F/(M_1+M_2)$. Normal force of $M_1$ on $M_2$ is what accelerates $M_2$. So force of $M_1$ on $M_2$ is given by $M_2*F/(M_1+M_2)$.